Data output to a table
I am making a website project for the work of the university's educational department, and I need to display the couples' schedule for the week.
I have such data that I receive from the API.
[
    {
        "Monday": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subjectname": "Алгоритмы и вычислительные методы оптимизации",
                "formatsubject": "Практика",
                "teacher": "Куанышев В. Т.",
                "groupname": "ПЕ-12б",
                "numberpair": 1,
                "date_subject": "2024-04-22",
                "auditorium": "405 УК1"
            },
            {
                "auditorium": "303 УК1",
                "date_subject": "2024-04-22",
                "numberpair": 2,
                "groupname": "ПЕ-12б",
                "teacher": "Бурумбаев Д. И.",
                "formatsubject": "Практика",
                "subjectname": "Сетевое программирование",
                "id": 4
            },
         ...
            {
                "auditorium": "",
                "date_subject": "",
                "numberpair": 7,
                "groupname": "",
                "teacher": "",
                "formatsubject": "",
                "subjectname": "",
                "id": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Tuesday": [...]
    },
    {
        "Wednesday": [...]
    },
    {
        "Thursday": [...]
    },
    {
        "Friday": [...]
    },
    {
        "Saturday": [...]
    }
]

I want to display them in a table in which the columns would contain the days of the week, and the rows would contain the numbers of classes. The cells of the table themselves would contain information about the name of the couple, who leads it and in which office. That's about it.
Click
I tried using Map to iterate over all the days of the week, but each day of the week has its own array with classes, and I do not know how to iterate over it.
import axios from "axios";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function Table() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getallshedule?date_start=2024-04-22&date_end=2024-04-27&groupname=ПЕ-12б')
        .then(res => setData(res.data))
        .catch(er => console.log(er));
    }, [])
    

    return (
        
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pair</th>
                        <th>Monday</th>
                        <th>Tuesday</th>
                        <th>Wednesday</th>
                        <th>Thursday</th>
                        <th>Friday</th>
                        <th>Saturday</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        data.map((day, index) => (
                            
                            <tr key = {index}>
                                <td>{day.subjectname}</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table;

Please tell me how to do this, if necessary, I can rewrite the data output format.

Could you be more clear on what to be displayed in the rows for a single column

Each column is a day of the week, and the rows are the class number in the schedule for each day of the week

What should be inside a cell, for example, from the api data  what should be inside class number 1 on monday .

Each cell should contain the name of the class, the teacher, and the room number.

Ok, got it, so the numnber of rows for a column is fixed right , i.e 7

Yes, 7 is a fixed number.

Thank you for the information, one last question, so the data in the cell is decided by the  "id" or "numberpair" so if its monday and its the 1st class should I display the data that is having id=1 or numberpair =1

In the schedule, the order of classes for the day is determined by numberpair

Thank you, will add the answer shortly !!

import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Table() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [modifiedData, setmodifiedData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:8080/getallshedule?date_start=2024-04-22&date_end=2024-04-27&groupname=ПЕ-12б"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        let modifiedDataT = [
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ];
        const arr = [
          "Monday",
          "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday",
          "Thursday",
          "Friday",
          "Saturday",
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          if (data[i] && data[i][arr[i]]) {
            let classesforDay = data[i][arr[i]];
            console.log(classesforDay);
            for (let index = 0; index < classesforDay.length; index++) {
              let obj = classesforDay[index];
              console.log(obj);
              modifiedDataT [obj["numberpair"] - 1][i] =
                obj["subjectname"] +
                "\n" +
                obj["teacher"] +
                "\n" +
                obj["auditorium"];
            }
          }
        }
        setmodifiedData(modifiedDataT);
      })
      .catch((er) => console.log(er));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Pair</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          
          {modifiedData.map((x, i) => (
            <tr>
              <td> {i + 1} </td>
              <td> {modifiedData[i][0]} </td>
              <td> {modifiedData[i][1]} </td>
              <td> {modifiedData[i][2]} </td>
              <td> {modifiedData[i][3]} </td>
              <td> {modifiedData[i][4]} </td>
              <td> {modifiedData[i][5]} </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;


Thank you very much, it works just fine, I've been thinking about this problem for several days.
